Remove values from array attribute of JSON column
I have a json (not jsonb) column in a PostgreSQL (version 13.12) table from which I want to remove specific values of an array attribute.
For example, in the following table (db-fiddle) I want to remove all occurrences of "D" from the actions attributes.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test;
CREATE TABLE test (
  data JSON
);
INSERT INTO test VALUES
  ('{"name": "Alice", "actions": ["B", "C", "D"]}'),
  ('{"name": "Charles", "actions": ["C", "D", "E"]}');
SELECT * FROM test;

How can I do this with a query?

Are you asking for a SELECT query with a result that doesn't contain the "D"s, or for an UPDATE query that removes them from the values in the table?

Good question. I'm looking for the UPDATE query.

Just select:
SELECT jsonb_set(data::jsonb, '{actions}', (data->'actions')::jsonb - 'D') AS data
FROM   test;

Yields jsonb, optionally cast back to json.
Update:
UPDATE test
SET    data = jsonb_set(data::jsonb, '{actions}', (data->'actions')::jsonb - 'D');

jsonb is coerced back to json in the assignment automatically.
View on DB Fiddle
Core feature is the jsonb operator -:

jsonb - text → jsonb
Deletes a key (and its value) from a JSON object, or matching string value(s) from a JSON array.

Using jsonb would remove the need to cast.

select json_build_object('name', name, 'actions', json_agg(action)) as data
from (select data ->> 'name' as name, t.action
      from test,
           lateral json_array_elements_text(data -> 'actions') t(action)
      where action <> 'D') tmp
group by name;

Output:



data




{"name" : "Alice", "actions" : ["B", "C"]}


{"name" : "Charles", "actions" : ["C", "E"]}




This query should do the trick, however, use a jsonb column if it's feasible and get rid of all type castings in the query
UPDATE test
SET data = CAST(jsonb_set(data::jsonb,'{actions}',(SELECT jsonb_agg(element) 
         FROM jsonb_array_elements(data::jsonb->'actions') AS element
         WHERE element != '"D"')) AS json
)
WHERE data::jsonb->'actions' @> '"D"';


You seem to be looking for the - operator on jsonb:
UPDATE test
SET data['actions'] = data['actions']::jsonb - 'D';

Although with Postgres 13, you'll need to use jsonb_set instead of the modern syntax:
UPDATE test
SET data = jsonb_set(data::jsonb, '{actions}', (data->'actions')::jsonb - 'D');

